# Testing confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I currently have constructed a 95% confidence interval and have then used `replicate()` to randomly generate 1000 confidence intervals. I want to measure how many of the intervals contain my mean. I know in theory it should be in 950 of them but how do I get a definite answer? The function I used and the mean are listed below.

```
z <- function(a,b,c){
  error <- rnorm(a, b, c) * c / sqrt(a) 
  left <- b - error
  right <- j + error
  paste("[",round(left,2),";",round(right,2),"]") 
}

set.seed(123)
replicate(1000, z(10,1,1))
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I can't make much sense of your `z()` function. Could you format it better/tidy it up?

Comment: @AkselA is that better?

Comment: It still looks like non-sense :). Have you written functions in R before?

Comment: No I'm new to R. It generates the 1000 confidence intervals but how do I then test if the mean is contained in each confidence interval?

Comment: Confidence interval of what? Estimating the mean of a normal distribution?

Comment: @JohnFitz Where does `j` come from?

Comment: Never return a character string from a function if you want to do further calculations with it. Simply return `c(left, right)` instead. I also do not understand your calculation of `error` (why multiply with `c`?) or, in fact, your whole approach.

Comment: I removed a `}` in my edit because otherwise you get a syntax error. Please reviewr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're trying to do?

This `z()` will return the confidence interval for the population mean of a normal distribution.

```
z <- function(N, mu, std, cl=95) {
    alpha <- (1-cl/100)/2

    # CI for population mean
    sep <- std/sqrt(N)
    z_s <- qnorm(1 - alpha)
    pop_lower <- mu - z_s*sep
    pop_upper <- mu + z_s*sep

    c(lower=pop_lower, upper=pop_upper)
}
```

Meaning that if I produce a random variate `mean(rnorm(20, 0, 1))`, then we expect the value of that to lie within `z(20, 0, 1, 95)` with probability 0.95.

To test this we can do

```
# specify parameters
N <- 20
mu <- 0
std <- 1

# produce a good number (10,000) of population means
set.seed(1)
r <- replicate(1e4, mean(rnorm(N, mu, std)))

# calculate confidence interval
ci <- z(N, mu, std)

# find which are below, within and above the interval
rc <- cut(r, c(min(r), ci, max(r)), c("below", "within", "above"))

# create a proportion table
round(prop.table(table(rc))*100, 2)

# below within  above 
#  2.59  95.08   2.33
```